# CPU mining JSON_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum

I just wanted to mine ETH with my CPU. I use Windows 7 64 Bit with ethminer.

I started the cpu miner with a batch

```
ethminer -t 6 -C -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=5@0x17C0Bea7c44*******9569EBA3d9B605CF2@RigCPU
```

It starts up and starts mining with about .5-.6 MH/s but after about 1 minute i get

> Exception -32700 JSON_PARSE_ERROR: The JSON-Object is not JASON-Valid: Database Error

I have no idea how I could solve this.

CPU is an i7 3630QM

Answer (score 15):

In reference to this:
http://ethpool.org/

"If you receive frequent "JSON-RPC Problem" errors try to increase your --farm-recheck value.
You should find a valid share every 1-2 minutes. If it constantly takes you longer to find a share try to lower your hashrate values (minimum is 0.1)."

Answer (score 5):

Ethminer.exe is not allowed to get through the windows firewall.

You must add ethminer.exe to the exceptions in `Control-Center` -> `Windows-Firewall`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with that pool... I believe Farm mode (-F) uses a bit of JSON to talk back and forth.

I'd try it with a different pool (nanopool, coinotron, suprnova, etc.) and see if you get the same error.

---

Confirmed that this is likely the problem: "Geth however can be used in conjunction with ethminer, using the standalone miner as workers and geth as scheduler **communicating via JSON-RPC**."

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining#mining-software

Use a different pool.